# can't find my local Boost distribution instead of the installed one despite using BOOST_ROOT

Tags: linux, boost, cmake

I have a question regarding FindBoost. I'm trying to select boost components from my own boost 1.49 distribution on an HPC (redhat) that already has a default boost 1.47 pre-installed.
I'd like to use mine exclusively, and I've been trying to use BOOST_ROOT as a cache variable, an internal cache variable, and an environment variable using set(ENV{BOOST_ROOT} ), but nothing works: I can see that BOOST_ROOT is properly set (points to the 1.49.0 version), but it seems that it has no effect on the library paths generated by FindBoost: they all point to libraries in the 1.47.0 version.
I'm trying this:

```
# I give a chance to the user to set BOOST_PATH to the local boost distribution before calling FindBoost
if( NOT DEFINED BOOST_PATH)
    message(STATUS " Set BOOST_PATH to a specific Boost distribution if needed.")
    set(BOOST_PATH "Default" CACHE PATH "Set the path to a specific Boost distribution if not default.")

# On the second pass, I use BOOST_PATH to initialize BOOST_ROOT, hoping that FindBoost will use it to find my local version.
else(   NOT DEFINED BOOST_PATH)
    if( NOT (BOOST_PATH MATCHES "Default"))
        set(BOOST_ROOT ${BOOST_PATH} CACHE PATH "path to the preferred boost distribution.")
    endif(NOT (BOOST_PATH MATCHES "Default"))

    # I test to make sure the path in   BOOST_ROOT is what I expect: it is on the console, as well as in the cache
    message("BOOST_ROOT = ${BOOST_ROOT}")

    set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      ON)
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON)
    set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS    "1.42" "1.42.0" 
                             "1.43" "1.43.0" 
                             "1.44" "1.44.0" 
                             "1.45" "1.45.0" 
                             "1.46" "1.46.0" "1.46.1"
                             "1.47" "1.47.0"
                             "1.48" "1.48.0"
                             "1.49" "1.49.0"
                             ${BOOST_ADDITIONAL_VERSION}
    )
    set(Boost_DEBUG                  TRUE) # Debugging info output for FindBoost
    set(Boost_DETAILED_FAILURE_MSG   TRUE) # Set to FALSE by default


    # I invoke FindBoost here, but although BOOST_ROOT points to my local boost, all the paths of the 3 components points to the installed debug/release variants, not to my local distribution.  
    find_package( Boost COMPONENTS date_time filesystem system program_options )

# unimportant code
[...]

endif(  NOT DEFINED BOOST_PATH)
```

I would greatly appreciate if you can help me. Thank you very much in advance.

Nicolas

Comment: Perhaps reordering BOOST_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS such that 1.49 is first?

Comment: And you set Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS to the value of BOOST_ADDITIONAL_VERSION (note: without the 's').

Comment: @Andre: I reordered the versions so that 1.49.0 is first, as you suggested, and... it worked!!! That's worrying, however: only the latest version of Boost will be used. What if someone has good reasons to use an older version, then? Anyways, it works now. Thanks a lot for your suggestions!

Comment: I would guess that FindBoost searches the list in order and stops searching as soon as it finds the first one fitting the requirements. There is quite a lengthy description of what FindBoost does with the BOOST_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS in the FindBoost.cmake in your cmake-modules directory.

Comment: I'll look into it, and post if I come up with a solution. Thanks Andre!

Answer (score 4):

In newer versions of `FindBoost.cmake` (CMake 2.8.x) there is a variable which can be set to influence the search path where the script is looking for Boost.

It is called `Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS` and if it is set to `TRUE` the libraries installed in system locations are not looked at.

I had to do this in some of my projects because the libraries of two Boost installations got mixed up by the find_package() script.